# Swapping software on external drives then changing drive letter

Tags: external-drive

I received a new external SSD from Santa :-) I have software that runs on an older external drive. Can I transfer the contents of the old drive to the new SSD then swap drive letters to save reinstalling the software.

Comment: I know how to change drive letters, I am asking if software and associated data installed on an  external drive say "D" is moved to another faster external drive say "E" and the drive letters swapped so the new drive becomes "D" and the old drive becomes "E" wiill the installed software still operate as it did previously.

Comment: Useless fucking site....